# Possible to give highcharts vertical legend labels consistent spacing across devices?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

My site generates a lap chart for a bunch of riders, like so:

[image]

The problem is, on some devices the legends don't line up.  E.g. if it's perfect in one browser, it stretches a bit too far in others, presumably due to font rendering differences.  (I have it set to Roboto).

The API documents the possibility of using `lineHeight` css property in itemStyle, but it doesn't seem to work for me.  I've set it to 50 and '50px', both in "legend" and "legend: itemStyle".  No good.

(http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.lineHeight)

As such the best I can do is fiddle with the fontsize and the itemMarginBottom, which leads me to the problem I have.

Anyone have a solution?

I'm using the latest version of highcharts by the way.

Comment: For now I've "fixed" this by removing the legend and placing a datalabel for each series where x=0 in the legend's place.  Feels kludgy, but essentially works.

Comment: Could you recreate your exampel as live demo ?